# Set the SelectedValue to Collection[Index] in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm using the below `XAML` to populate a `ListBox`. I have already set the `DataContext` to a static collection (Elevations) in a static class (Building).

I'm always storing the index of the current elevation in the Elevations collection as a property of the Building: **CurrentElevationIndex**

Now I want to set the `SelectedValue` to `Building.Elevations[Building.CurrentElevationIndex]`

I don't need it to be changed. It is a one time thing. I only need it to be set when the Window starts.

```
    <ListBox x:Name="PlanElevationsList"
             DataContext="{x:Static building:Building.Elevations}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             SelectedValue="">
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be OneTime and set at window start then Building.CurrentElevationIndex must be known at that time. so, why not to set it like `Building.Elevations[0]` for instance. *(Assuming 0th index will be default at load)*

```
<ListBox x:Name="PlanElevationsList"
         DataContext="{x:Static building:Building.Elevations}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         SelectedValue="{x:Static building:Building.Elevations[0]}"/>
```

---

In case CurrentElevationIndex is not known at startup you can have a wrapper property in class to return that value.
However, converter might be a way to go but for OneTime operation seems not a valid approach.

```
public static string SelectedElevation
{
   get
   {
      return Elevations[CurrentElevationIndex];
   }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="PlanElevationsList"
         DataContext="{x:Static building:Building.Elevations}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         SelectedValue="{x:Static building:Building.SelectedElevation}"/>
```

---

*Update for comment*:

> What if I'm defining the SelectedElevation property in the Window.cs
>   itself not in the building. How can I set the selectedvalue in this
>   case?

You can bind it using **`RelativeSource`** with AncestorType set to Window:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElevation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                            FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Mode=OneTime}"
```

Also you can set **`x:Name`** on window and bind using ElementName:

```
<Window x:Name="myWindow">
   ....
   <ListBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedElevation, ElementName=myWindow, 
                                    Mode=OneTime}">
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit, What if I'm defining the `SelectedElevation` property in the Window.cs itself not in the building. How can I set the selectedvalue in this case?